# javascript print Contents fitting to one page

Tags: javascript

with this function, I can print div content succesfully but I want to fitting one  horizantal page . How can I do that?

```
function printDiv(divId) {
    var printContents = document.getElementById(divId).innerHTML;
     var originalContents = document.body.innerHTML;
     document.body.innerHTML = printContents;
     window.print();
     document.body.innerHTML = originalContents;
    
  return true;
}
```

Comment: you'd need css for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In CSS, you can use the @media print label to size your div to fit a whole page, like

```
@media print {
  div { /*page with 1 inch margins */
    height: 9in;
    width: 6.5in;
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks.  Its fitting now. Also  I want to output will be  horizantal selcect automatichly print to pdf. Have any idea?

Comment: @user3191435 No idea